# RunTime Exception LibGDX ERROR but why is it complaining about a TextureRegion?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

So MenuScreen is working fine, but I can't understand why I'm getting this error.
It happens on commencement of the actual game after start game is pressed on the start menu.

[image: StackTrace]

```
public class NinjaRabbitGraphicsProcessor implements GraphicsProcessor, Telegraph {
    private static final String WALK_REGION = "walk";
    private static final String JUMP_REGION = "jump";
    // private static final String DUCK_REGION = "duck";
    private static final Vector2 RESPAWN_POSITION = new Vector2(0.6f, 3.2f);

    private final TextureAtlas textureAtlas;
    private final Box2DSprite standingSprite;
    private final AnimatedBox2DSprite walkRightSprite;
    private final AnimatedBox2DSprite walkLeftSprite;
    private final AnimatedBox2DSprite jumpSprite;

    // private final AnimatedBox2DSprite duckSprite;

    public NinjaRabbitGraphicsProcessor(final AssetManager assets) {
        textureAtlas = assets.get(Assets.NINJA_RABBIT_ATLAS);

        Array<Sprite> walkingSprites = textureAtlas.createSprites(WALK_REGION);
        standingSprite = new Box2DSprite(walkingSprites.first());
        standingSprite.setAdjustSize(false);
        standingSprite.setSize(standingSprite.getWidth() / NinjaRabbitGame.PPM,
                standingSprite.getHeight() / NinjaRabbitGame.PPM);

        Animation animation = new Animation(1 / 12.0f, walkingSprites, Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
        walkRightSprite = new AnimatedBox2DSprite(new AnimatedSprite(animation));
        walkRightSprite.setAdjustSize(false);
        walkRightSprite.setSize(walkRightSprite.getWidth() / NinjaRabbitGame.PPM,
                walkRightSprite.getHeight() / NinjaRabbitGame.PPM);

        animation = new Animation(1 / 12.0f, textureAtlas.createSprites(WALK_REGION), Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
        walkLeftSprite = new AnimatedBox2DSprite(new AnimatedSprite(animation));
        walkLeftSprite.flipFrames(true, false, true);
        walkLeftSprite.setAdjustSize(false);
        walkLeftSprite.setSize(walkLeftSprite.getWidth() / NinjaRabbitGame.PPM,
                walkLeftSprite.getHeight() / NinjaRabbitGame.PPM);

        animation = new Animation(1 / 10.0f, textureAtlas.createSprites(JUMP_REGION));
        jumpSprite = new AnimatedBox2DSprite(new AnimatedSprite(animation));
        jumpSprite.setAdjustSize(false);
        jumpSprite.setSize(jumpSprite.getWidth() / NinjaRabbitGame.PPM,
                jumpSprite.getHeight() / NinjaRabbitGame.PPM);



        MessageManager.getInstance().addListener(this, MessageType.DEAD.code());
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     *
     * @see ar.uba.fi.game.graphics.GraphicsProcessor#update(ar.uba.fi.game.entity.Entity,
     * com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Camera)
     */
    @Override
    public void update(final Entity character, final Camera camera) {
        camera.position.x = character.getBody() == null ? 0.0f :
                character.getBody().getPosition().x + camera.viewportWidth * 0.25f;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     *
     * @see ar.uba.fi.game.entity.GraphicsProcessor#draw(com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch)
     */
    @Override
    public void draw(final Entity character, final Batch batch) {
        Box2DSprite frame = null;

        if (character.isInState(NinjaRabbitState.JUMP)) {
            jumpSprite.flipFrames(!(Direction.RIGHT.equals(character.getDirection()) ^ jumpSprite.isFlipX()), false, false);
            frame = jumpSprite;
        } else if (character.isInState(NinjaRabbitState.RIGHT)) {
            frame = walkRightSprite;
            character.setDirection(Direction.RIGHT);
        } else if (character.isInState(NinjaRabbitState.LEFT)) {
            frame = walkLeftSprite;
            character.setDirection(Direction.LEFT);
        } else if (character.isInState(NinjaRabbitState.DUCK)) {
            // frame = duckSprite;
        } else {
            standingSprite.flip(!(Direction.RIGHT.equals(character.getDirection()) ^ standingSprite.isFlipX()), false);
            frame = standingSprite;
            // duckSprite.setTime(0.0f);
            jumpSprite.setTime(0.0f);
        }

        // Following numbers came from voodoo
        frame.setPosition(
                -frame.getWidth() * 0.5f +
                        Box2DUtils.width(character.getBody()) / (Direction.RIGHT.equals(character.getDirection())
                                ? 2.8f : 1.55f),
                -frame.getHeight() * 0.5f + Box2DUtils.width(character.getBody()) + 0.36f);

        frame.draw(batch, character.getBody());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(final Telegram msg) {
        Entity character = (Entity) msg.extraInfo;
        character.getBody().setTransform(RESPAWN_POSITION, character.getBody().getAngle());
        character.changeState(NinjaRabbitState.IDLE);
        character.setDirection(Direction.RIGHT);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(final int width, final int height) {
    }
}
```

I have no compile-time errors obviously so I can't find where this should be.

An help greatly appreciated. Please elaborate.

[repo](https://github.com/BenMohammad/theninjarabbit)

Answer (score 0):

Had to change build.gradle to earlier version I used 1.9.3 now it works fine.